# Dexie DB liveQuery multiple collections

Tags: dexie

I'm currently using DexieDB to store data in 10 different collections.
When a user is navigating to a single page, I collect data from these 10 different collections as the data source.
The main collection has an identifier that is being used to get the corresponding data from the other collections.

With the new liveQuery update I managed to get this working for a single collection, but I was wondering if I were to use it for multiple collection what the best approach would be.

Would it be better to create multiple subscriptions for the collections that need to be watched (not all of them), or would it be possible to create 1 subscription over multiple collections?

I looked in the docs, but all the examples include only one collection, and there isn't any documentation on how this would work with multiple collections.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are possible. If you are in a Component based GUI framework (React, Angular, Svelte etc), one subscription per query is normally what to prefer becuase by splitting it so, a mutation affecting the query on the related collection will only trigger a re-render of its component instead of re-rendering also its parent.

That said, you can also perfectly well perform multiple queries within your callback to liveQuery and return an array or object containing the data. That way you will implicitly subscribe to all the visited queries.